# I failed to solve a set of one-dimension fluid mechanics PDEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, fluid-dynamics

The fluid here has been assumed as single component perfect gas i.e. it obeys the equation $p=ρ R T$, the thermal conductivity is assumed as a constant, so the equation set is:

```
NDSolve[{D[ρg[t, x], t] + D[ρg[t, x] u[t, x], x] == 0,

         ρg[t, x] D[u[t, x], t] + ρg[t, x] u[t, x] D[u[t, x],x] 
          == -D[ρg[t, x] te[t, x], x],

         ρg[t, x] D[te[t, x], t] + ρg[t, x] u[t, x] D[te[t, x],x]
          == -ρg[t, x] te[t, x] D[u[t, x], x] + D[te[t, x], x, x],

         te[0, x] == 298, te[t, -0.5] == 298, te[t, 0.5] == 298,

         ρg[0, x] == (1 - x^2),

         u[0, x] == 0, u[t, -0.5] == 0, u[t, 0.5] == 0},

        {ρg[t, x], te[t, x], u[t, x]}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

After I ran the code, I only got the warning message `NDSolve::ndsz` and `NDSolve::eerr`, I've checked the the equations for times and I think they are correct, and the initial and boundary conditions are also simple and seems to be reasonable (at least from the perspective of physics). So…What's wrong with it?…Well, to tell you the truth, what I really want to ask is, does `NDSolve` lack the ability to solve system of partial differential equations?

Oh, someone may feel strange that there's no boundary condition for `ρg[t, x]`, that's because, I found that only four boundary conditions are necessary for the solving of the equations though I don't know the exact reason (I found it in times of trial when I set `ρg[0, x]` as a constant ).

Comment: Did you check carefully all signs for all terms? Can this be just a typo with sign leading to sort of exp growth?

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov After I saw your comment I checked all signs for another time, and…I still don't find any mistake…

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov Er…what about [this](http://www10.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Teaching/Courses/SS2009/NuSiF/NuSiF-Grundgl-engl.pdf)? See the _5.17_, _5,31_, _5.77_. (Of course we still need some deformation to get the form for the one-dimensional cases.)

Comment: 5.77 seems to differ quite a bit from your implementation. Sure you're correct there?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think you mean the expression involved τ (shear stress), right? Since the fluid here is ideal gas (oh, maybe I should say perfect gas for it's in the field of Fluid Mechanics), it's zero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the experience gained in past 6 years, I manage to find out a more efficient solution for this problem :D .

This problem turns out to be another example on which the difference scheme implemented in `NDSolve` doesn't work well. The issue has been discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129183/1871). Equipped with the `fix` function therein, the `ndsz` warning no longer pops up. Though the `eerr` warning remains, the estimated error is small, and the result is consistent with the one in ruebenko (now [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21))'s answer.

```
xL = -1/2; xR = 1/2;

With[{T = T[t, x], ρ = ρ[t, x], u = u[t, x]},

 eq = {D[ρ, t] + D[ρ u, x] == 0,
       D[u, t] + u D[u, x] == -(1/ρ) D[ρ T, x],
       D[T, t] + u D[T, x] == -T D[u, x] + 1/ρ D[T, x, x]};

 ic = {T == 298, ρ == (1 - x^2), u == 0} /. t -> 0;

 bc = {{T == 298, u == 0} /. x -> xL, {T == 298, u == 0} /. x -> xR};]

endtime = 0.2; difforder = 2; points = 300;

mol[n : _Integer | {_Integer ..}, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
        "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines",
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf, "ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

(* Definition of fix isn't included in this post, 
   please find it in the link above. *)
mysol = fix[endtime, difforder]@
    NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, {ρ, T, u}, {t, 0, endtime}, {x, xL, xR}, 
     Method -> Union[mol[False], mol[points, difforder]], 
     MaxStepFraction -> {1/10^4, Infinity}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.111344, Null} *)

(* Please find definition of sol in user21's answer. *)
Manipulate[Table[
  Plot[{sol[[1, i, -1]], mysol[[i]][t, x]} // Evaluate, {x, xL, xR}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[{Thick, Dashed}]}], 
   {i, 3}], {t, 0, endtime}]
```

[image]

Just for comparison, in *v9.0.1*, ruebenko's solution takes about `35` seconds to finish computing with `nxy = 33`, and about `170` seconds with **`nxy = 43`**. (Yes, the speed drops dramatically when `nxy` increases. )

**Remark**

1. I choose `T` instead of `te` when coding equation in this answer, because it's more straightforward and I believe `T` is unlikely to be introduced as a built-in symbol in the future.
2. `MaxStepFraction` option can be taken away, and `NDSolveValue` will solve the system in less than `3` seconds then, but the solution will be slightly noisy in some region, for example:

   ```
   Plot[{sol[[1, 3, -1]], mysol[[3]][t, x]} /. t -> 0.187 // Evaluate, {x, xL, xR}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[{Thick, Dashed}]}]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
3. `mol[False]` i.e. `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> False` can be taken away, but `NDSolveValue` will be slower without it.
4. The difference between `sol` and `mysol` is relatively obvious in certain moment e.g. `t == 0.187`, but further check by adjusting `points` shows `mysol` seems to be the reliable one.
5. Though I can't figure it out at the moment, I suspect there exists even more suitable way to discretize the system, given the precedent [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133315/1871).

Comment: It's always nice when people come back to questions they previously asked, armed with better understanding. :)

Answer (score 36):

Perhaps setting the difference order to 
`"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"` is what you are looking for:

```
showStatus[status_] := 
  LinkWrite[$ParentLink, 
   SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
    ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[] := showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]
nxy = 33;
sol = NDSolve[{D[ρg[t, x], t] + D[ρg[t, x] u[t, x], x] == 
   0, ρg[t, x] D[u[t, x], t] + ρg[t, x] u[t, x] D[u[t, x], 
      x] == -D[ρg[t, x] te[t, x], 
     x], ρg[t, x] D[te[t, x], t] + ρg[t, x] u[t, x] D[
      te[t, x], x] == -ρg[t, x] te[t, x] D[u[t, x], x] + 
    D[te[t, x], x, x], te[0, x] == 298, te[t, -0.5] == 298, 
  te[t, 0.5] == 298, ρg[0, x] == (1 - x^2), u[0, x] == 0, 
  u[t, -0.5] == 0, u[t, 0.5] == 0}, {ρg[t, x], te[t, x], 
  u[t, x]}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -0.5, 0.5},
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MaxPoints" -> nxy, "MinPoints" -> nxy, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}, Method -> "Adams"},
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> showStatus["t = " <> ToString[CForm[t]]]];
```

The `Method->Adams` is not necessary.

Depicted below is how the solutions look. To avoid scales incongruousness they are visualized on different plots.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[{#[t, x]} /. sol], {t, 0, .2}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, 
    Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.2], 
    ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7], 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40, ImageSize -> 200, 
    PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {ρg, u, te} // Row
```

[image]

Comment: any chance of making it faster? Is it the optimal speed for `NDSolve`?

Comment: @ruebenko Big +1 - I am in awe you got this to work. I was almost sure there is an intrinsic divergence. I was also trying "Pseudospectral" with cyclic BC but to no avail. I am still puzzled why this works an nothing else does. I took a liberty to plot the beautiful solutions. Please feel free to remove my edit if you feel it's inappropriate.

Comment: @ruebenko: can you explain how you found that exactly this combination of options does work? Do you have a strategy how to find a working set of parameters or are you using a clever combination of experience+guessing+trying? If you could explain, that would probably make the answer even more valuable, you eared a +1 anyway...

Comment: @ruebenko Wonderful!…well, but I wonder what's the minimum system requirements for the code?

Comment: @PlatoManiac, there are a few things you can try: not using the `EvaluationMonitor` and/or using a lower `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` - with lowering those you may get away with using a smaller grid too.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, thanks for adding the pictures.

Comment: @xzczd, I am not sure what the minimum is, I uses a Linux-x86-64 with 4GB memory and did not have any problems.

Comment: @AlbertRetey, in this case the error message `NDSolve::ndsz` made me try `Method->Adams` (which actually is not needed) as an alternative to the automatic stiffness switching. `NDSolve::eerr:` made me choose my own grid. The `DifferenceOrder` was because OP mentioned something about the boundary conditions in the post and that made me think this might be worth a try. So, yes, some experience and a try. I do have a note where I collect these type of questions and solutions that are found for them and then I consult this when needed. This might be something for a community wiki.

Comment: @ruebenko Hehe, after times of trial I found my computer with 2GB memory can only bear a _t_ around 0.736 at most…

Comment: @ruebenko Well, where can I find the details of those methods for NDSolve? The document seems not say much about them…by the way, OP is the abbreviation for what?

Comment: @xzczd, have a look at tutorial/NDSolvePDE (enter this in the help brwoser). Also, if you go to the NDSolve reference page there are a bunch of tutorials. Among them is tutorial/NDSolveOverview. Sorry, OP means original poster - so you in this case ;-).

Comment: @ruebenko: thanks for the explanation (I'm late, haven't been on my computer for a while...)

Comment: As late as this is, changing the `Method` from `Adams` to `LSODA` made is *really* fast to run.