# How to force the function to take positive value when solving PDE by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I try to solve this PDE

```
 testmodel001 = 
 NDSolve[{D[CO2P[h, t], t] == 10^4 (h-100)^4 - 3*10^(-10) CO2P[h, t]*Exp[30 - 0.05 h],
 CO2P[h, 0] == 0
 }, {CO2P}, {h, 100, 250}, {t, 0, 200}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t}]
```

It's easy to see that `CO2P[h, t]` should always be positive(or zero), if it starts with non-negative value.

However, when I get the solution I found `CO2P[h, t]` get negative values for certain altitude (h) range. For example:

```
{#, (CO2P/.testmodel001[[1]])[#, 10]}&/@Range[100, 110, 0.1] // 
ListPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"h", "CO2P[t=10]"}] &
```

gives:

[image]

It seems `CO2P[h=101, t]` run to negative value very fast:

```
{#, ((CO2P/.testmodel001[[1]])[101, #])}&/@Range[0, 3, 0.05] // 
ListPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"t", "CO2P[h=101]"}, PlotRange -> All] &
```

gives:

[image]

What should I do to force my `CO2P[h, t]` to take positive value?

Notes: the PDE above is only an oversimplified toy model. The reallife PDEs I have to deal with is much more complicate (and contain D[X[h,t],h] terms). Is there a general way to **make sure** my function always take **positive value**?

Comment: It seems rather strange..because even `CO2P[h, t]` gets a negative value somehow, `D[CO2P[h, t], t] ==10^4 (h-100)^4 - 3*10^(-10) CO2P[h, t]*Exp[30 - 0.05 h]` is positive and should boost `CO2P[h, t]` back to positive...CO2P[h=101, t] gets larger and larger negative value, this is real hard to understand....

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10055/1871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interpolation problem due to the course grid in `h`.  For simplicity, label the solution `s` instead of `testmodel001`.  Then, the grid in `h` is

```
s["Coordinates"][[1]]
(* {100., 106.25, 112.5, 118.75, 125., 131.25, 137.5, 143.75, 150., 
    156.25, 162.5, 168.75, 175., 181.25, 187.5, 193.75, 200., 206.25, 
    212.5, 218.75, 225., 231.25, 237.5, 243.75, 250.} *)
```

Negative values shown in the plots in the question are an artifact of this coarseness.  In fact, no numerical value actually calculated by `NDSolve` is negative.

```
Min@Flatten@s["ValuesOnGrid"]
(* 0. *)
```

and selecting points coinciding with the grid points used by `NDSolve` would yield strictly positive plots.  To alleviate this problem, tell `NDSolve` to use a finer mesh, for instance,

```
s = NDSolveValue[{D[CO2P[h, t], t] == 10^4 (h - 100)^4 - 3*10^(-10) 
    CO2P[h, t]*Exp[30 - 0.05 h], CO2P[h, 0] == 0}, CO2P, {h, 100, 250}, 
    {t, 0, 200}, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 150}}}]
```

Then,

```
Plot[s[h, 10], {h, 100, 110}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[s[101, t], {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]