# Piecewise Boundary Condition for axisymmetric heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, piecewise, discontinuity, axisymmetry

I'm trying to solve the 2D axisymmetric heat equation, where only one section of the tube is being heated up. I have written the following code below:

```
q=Piecewise[{{0,z<=0},{10000t,0<=z}}]
bc1=q==1.38(D[T[r,z,t],r]/.r->0.03);
bc2=(D[T[r,z,t],r]/.r->0.00001)==0;
ic1=T[r,z,0]==273.15;

heat=(1521740*D[T[r,z,t],t])==D[T[r,z,t],r,r]+D[T[r,z,t],r]+D[T[r,z,t],z,z];
sol=NDSolve[{heat,bc1,bc2,ic1},{T},{r,0.00001,0.03},{z,-0.2,0.2},{t,0,100}]
```

However, I get the error NDSolve: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t==0`.
The code works when I change q=10000t instead. I think something is likely wrong with the piecewise boundary condition but I'm not sure what is wrong.

---

Edit:
After updating q, the code is able to run but the result seems unphysical (The temperature in some section decreases). It seems like the boundary condition bc1 isnt being properly obeyed.

```
q=Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{0,z<=0},{10000t,0<=z}}]
bc1=q==1.38(D[T[r,z,t],r]/.r->0.03);
bc2=(D[T[r,z,t],r]/.r->0.00001)==0;
bc3 = (D[T[r, z, t], z] /. z -> 0.2) == 0;
bc4 = (D[T[r, z, t], z] /. z -> -0.2) == 0;
ic1=T[r,z,0]==273.15;

heat=(1521740*D[T[r,z,t],t])==D[T[r,z,t],r,r]+D[T[r,z,t],r]+D[T[r,z,t],z,z];
sol=NDSolve[{heat,bc1,bc2,bc3,bc4,ic1},{T},{r,0.00001,0.03},{z,-0.2,0.2},{t,0,100}]
Interpolation[Table[{r, sol[[1, 1, 2]][r, -0.01, 10]}, {r, 0.0001, 0.03, 
 0.0001}]]'[0.03]
```

The interpolation helps to evaluate the partial derivative of r at z=-0.01. Based on the Piecewise function bc1, this should be 0. However, the interpolation gives me -6247.

Comment: To be more specific, change definition of `q` to ``q = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{0, z <= 0}, {10000 t, 0 <= z}}]`` avoids the `ndnum` warning. You still need to fix the `bcart` warning, though. Please notice `bcart` is a serious problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871

Comment: Instead of bc1 and bc2,  include a `10000 t /1.38 NeumannValue[1, r == .03 && z <= 0 ]` in your pde..

Comment: @xzczd Introducing `NeumannValue` simply solves the problem I think. No need to use the link! That's why I propose to reopen the question

Comment: @UlrichNeumann 1. Since OP wrote "I'm not sure what is wrong" I think the topic of the post is to understand what's wrong with the code. If OP clarifies further and make the post not a duplicate, I'll vote to reopen. 2. I think turning to FEM isn't a good idea in this case, because FEM will automatically add zero Neumann condition in `z` direction, but at the moment we just don't know what b.c.s OP needs in `z` direction.

Comment: @xzczd Ok let's wait, thanks. But it's not to difficult to add convection bc[z]  with FEM...

Comment: @xzczd Yes changing the definition of q helped to solve the issue. But I'm not entirely sure how it works... does q get changed into a single function? As for the bcart warning, I forgot to add the convection boundary conditions at the two ends.

Comment: In short, your original `q` doesn't work because of a bug of `NDSolve`, it's not your fault. (This might be related to the improper differentiation of `Piecewise[…]`. )

Comment: I see thanks, I've edited the code now and it's able to run, but it seems like the BC may not be properly applied. I've edited the question to add my new code and to describe the issue that arises. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Well, since the problem has totally changed, you should post a new question for it. Anyway, what you've observed is not surprising, because the `Piecewise` function is approximated with finite difference formula in this case. (If you choose FEM for spatial discretization, the situ will be slightly different, but similar. ) Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10055/1871