# 1D Euler equations (fluid dynamics) with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics, fluid-dynamics

Is it possible to *accurately* solve the 1D Euler equations in *Mathematica* using `NDSolve`?

For example, let us consider the **Sod shock tube** problem. Introduction to this problem can be found in the following links:

http://www.csun.edu/~jb715473/examples/euler1d.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod_shock_tube

Using the notation `{r, v, e}` for $(\rho,v,E)$ we can formulate the problem in *Mathematica* as:

```
g = 1.4;
p[x_, t_] := (g - 1) (e[x, t] - r[x, t] v[x, t]^2/2);
eqs = {
    D[r[x, t], t] + D[r[x, t] v[x, t], x] == 0,
    D[r[x, t] v[x, t], t] + D[r[x, t] v[x, t]^2 + p[x, t], x] == 0,
    D[e[x, t], t] + D[v[x, t] (e[x, t] + p[x, t]), x] == 0
};
```

and initial conditions

```
r0[x_] := 1.0 Boole[0 < x <= 0.5] + 0.25 Boole[0.5 < x <= 1.0];
v0[x_] := 0.0;
p0[x_] := 1.0 Boole[0 < x <= 0.5] + 0.1 Boole[0.5 < x <= 1.0];
```

Setting Dirichlet boundary conditions and throwing it into `NDSolve`:

```
ppR = 401;
ndsol = NDSolve[Join[eqs, {
    r[x, 0] == r0[x], r[0, t] == r0[0], r[1, t] == r0[1],
    v[x, 0] == v0[x], v[0, t] == v0[0], v[1, t] == v0[1],
    p[x, 0] == p0[x], p[0, t] == p0[0], p[1, t] == p0[1]}],
 {r, v, e}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1},
 MaxSteps -> 10^3, PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "Method" -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> Pseudospectral, "MaxPoints" -> {ppR}, 
  "MinPoints" -> {ppR}}}]
```

Taking the solution and plotting

```
DensityPlot[Evaluate[First[v[x, t] /. ndsol]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: Solution plot]

We see some nasty numerical errors. Is there anyway to get an accurate solution using `NDSolve`?

**Edit:** This paper suggests that the Method of Lines should apply: http://math.lanl.gov/~mac/papers/numerics/H79.pdf

Comment: Your link isn't working here

Comment: Strange... Is it something I did wrong?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9291/16) answer helps? but blind experimentation is not very satisfactory

Comment: I hammered on this for a while, and got nowhere.  BTW, I think in the r0[x_]:= its 0.125 (least of your worries) If you go through and make _everything_ a fraction e.g. 1.4 -> 14/10 then it doesn't even crank, crashing out with a 1/0 ComplexInfinity error...

Comment: Both links work fine for me. Perhaps the server was down for maintenance.

Comment: @DaleRoberts Your `NDSolve` cell errored out with signficant errors... is it `Pseudospectral` or `PseudoSpectral`? or am I missing something (because both didn't work). I also have a division by zero error.

Comment: @EricBrown How'd you go about it? This coupled set of equations is full of errors. [Here](http://pastebin.com/B2BMUN0L) is my edit. You'll notide that I am not using the boolean function

Comment: @drN Not Sure what you mean.  I was just trying different settings.  Ack, yours is full of errors.  = where there should be ==, {r,v,e} should be the variables, etc.  Dale's code looks fine to me, though, don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update-1:** The initial conditions in the question were wrong/incomplete. (removed 1/0 errors)

**Update-2:** The 1D Euler equations were modified to match this [source](http://www3.nd.edu/~gtryggva/CFD-Course/2011-Lecture-17.pdf). (ultimately not necessary in V10.4, but is in V8)

**Update-3:** `Method` options in `NDSolve` were modified to produce an accurate result. (ENO schemes are not yet supported, but the proposed answer below is robust enough to tackle a range of Euler fluid dynamic and MHD problems) **Problem Solved!**

```
eqs = {D[r[x, t], t] + D[r[x, t] v[x, t], x] == 0,
   D[r[x, t] v[x, t], t] + D[r[x, t] v[x, t]^2 + p[x, t], x] == 0,
   D[r[x, t] e[x, t], t] + D[r[x, t] v[x, t] (e[x, t] + p[x, t]/r[x, t]), x] == 0};

g = 1.4;
p[x_, t_] := (g - 1) r[x, t] (e[x, t] - v[x, t]^2/2);

(*Sod Shock Tube*)
r0[x_] := 1.0 Boole[0 <= x <= 0.5] + 0.125 Boole[0.5 < x <= 1.0];
v0[x_] := 0.0;
p0[x_] := 1.0 Boole[0 <= x <= 0.5] + 0.1 Boole[0.5 < x <= 1.0];

ppR = 400;

ndsol = NDSolve[Join[eqs,
    {r[x, 0] == r0[x], r[0, t] == r0[0], r[1, t] == r0[1],
     v[x, 0] == v0[x], v[0, t] == v0[0], v[1, t] == v0[1],
     p[x, 0] == p0[x], p[0, t] == p0[0], p[1, t] == p0[1]}],
   {r, v, e}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1},
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 1, AccuracyGoal -> 1, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> ppR, "MaxPoints" -> ppR, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
     Method -> {"Adams", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}}];

p1 = DensityPlot[
   Evaluate[First[r[x, t] /. ndsol]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Density"];
p2 = DensityPlot[
   Evaluate[First[v[x, t] /. ndsol]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Velocity"];
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}, ImageSize -> Large]

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[First[v[x, t] /. ndsol]], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], {t, 0, 0.1, 0.0025}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that the original definition for the i.c. misses the value at $x=0$. This does make things worse, but sadly the solution given by `NDSolve` still contains remarkable error even after correcting this. Just check the result of `Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[First[v[x, t] /. ndsol]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
  0.1}]`

Comment: @xzczd The result now accurately matches the reference solution in the original question!

Comment: Interesting, though there're still small oscillations (so I think it cannot be called _accurate_ :) ), now the solution is quite close to the correct one. Just a side note: there seems to be a bug in NDSolve of v9.0.1, if you run the code above in v9, the kernel will crash. v8.0.4 and v10.4.1 don't suffer the problem.

Comment: @xzczd I noticed small oscillations in the reference solution as well, but I agree that these are slightly larger. My proposed answer seems to advance the solution considerably (if not sufficiently) and shows `NDSolve` still has a few tricks =)

Comment: Wow, finally! I've been waiting a long time for this :)

Comment: @xzczd Is this answer worthy of the bounty you offered?

Comment: Of course, your answer is a real pleasant surprise to me, +26 :) . Just another side note: your modification for the form of equation isn't necessary in v10.4.1, but it's necessary in v8.0.4, or `NDSolve` won't give the correct result. (Seems that `NDSolve` is improved silently in some aspect in v10.)

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! Hopefully a ENO solver scheme will be available in the future and/or a Finite Element solver that can handle non-linear coefficients.

Comment: @Young very nice work! +1!

Answer (score 14):

This is a classical shock-tube problem in which a initially diaphragm separates a hi-pressure, high-density region from one of lower pressure and density. The classical exact solution has multiple discontinuities, a shock wave and a contact-surface (density discontinuity) that propagate to the right, and a continuous rarefaction wave traveling into the high-pressure gas.

The discontinuities cannot be captured by a pseudo spectral scheme,which produces the disastrous oscillations. This also occurs with many other spatial differencing schemes that have too little inherent dissipation. See the book *"Difference Methods for Initial Value Problems"* by Richtmeyer and Morton (1967), which discusses methods for adding "artificial viscosity" to the Euler equations. This enables the discontinuities to be successfully smeared out over multiple grid points.  There are many more modern methods that accomplish the same purpose. Try Googling the terms `"Roe Scheme, ENO Scheme, Flux-Difference Splitting."`

In short, Mathematica's `NDSolve[]` command is not yet able to handle directly the Euler equation flows that have discontinuous solutions, and this includes all mixed subsonic/supersonic flows such as your case. Theoretically, it should be able to handle subsonic flows, which are always continuous. Unfortunately, I have found to my dismay that `NDSolve[]` is not yet sophisticated enough to permit one to use the type of characteristics-based inflow and outflow boundary conditions that are an absolute necessity for generating stable, accurate subsonic flow solutions. I posted a question on this site two days ago, but the question was Closed Out (removed) by other more senior users who deemed it inappropriate. That question was titled "[NDSolve rejects a common non-reflective subsonic outflow boundary condition for the 1-D Euler equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24417/adapting-ndsolve-to-circumvent-ndsolvebdord-error-for-1-d-euler-equations)".

Comment: I have edited your closed question. You are raising correct issues here but you need to present the problem at hand in a right manner. Best of luck in future!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution by adding a very small viscosity `μ` to Euler equations (notice [Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)) can be seen as particular Navier–Stokes equations with zero viscosity and zero thermal conductivity):

```
γ = 1.4;
p[x_, t_] = (γ - 1) (Ε[x, t] - 1/2 ρ[x, t] v[x, t]^2);
eqs = With[{μ = 5 10^-4, ρ = ρ[x, t], v = v[x, t], p = p[x, t], Ε = Ε[x, t]},
   {D[ρ, t] + D[ρ v, x] == 0,
    D[ρ v, t] + D[ρ v^2 + p, x] == μ D[v, x, x](* <- The key point is here *),
    D[Ε, t] + D[v (Ε + p), x] == 0}];

ρ0[x_] = Piecewise[{{0.125, 0.5 < x <= 1}}, 1];
v0[x_] = 0;
p0[x_] = Piecewise[{{0.1, 0.5 < x <= 1}}, 1];

mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
        "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

{solρ, solv, solΕ} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqs, 
      {ρ[x, 0] == ρ0[x], ρ[0, t] == ρ0[0], ρ[1, t] == ρ0[1], 
       v[x, 0] == v0[x], v[0, t] == v0[0], v[1, t] == v0[1], 
       p[x, 0] == p0[x], p[0, t] == p0[0], p[1, t] == p0[1]}}, 
    {ρ, v, Ε}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1}, Method -> mol[400, 4]];
```

`μ` should be small enough but not too small, or `NDSolve` will fail again. A dense enough spatial grid is also necessary. Though the warnings `eerri` and `eerr`  generated, the obtained solution is in good agreement with the one given in OP's link:

```
Manipulate[GraphicsRow[
  Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 11/10}] & /@ {solρ[x, t], solv[x, t], 
    p[x, t] /. {ρ -> solρ, Ε -> solΕ, v -> solv}}, ImageSize -> 1000], {t, 0, 0.1}]
```

[image]