# Why does NonlinearStateSpaceModel linearise?

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems, modeling

The documentation for `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` says:

> In `NonlinearStateSpaceModel[eqns, ...]` the Taylor linearization is with 
>   respect to the highest-order derivatives of $x_i$ about the point 
>   ($x_{i0}$, $u_{i0}$) of the differential equations eqns.

Why does it linearise the equations? It is, after all, supposed to be a *nonlinear* state space model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider a model where the nonlinearity is in $x'(t)$ and not in the highest derivative $x''(t)$.

```
eq1 = {x''[t] + Sin[ x'[t]] + x[t] == u[t]};
```

Choose the first state as $x(t)$ (call it $\bar{x}_1(t)$) and the second state as $x'(t)$ (call it $\bar{x}_2(t)$) and we get the following equations.

$$ \bar{x}_1'(t)=\bar{x}_2(t)$$
$$ \bar{x}_2'(t)+\sin \left(\bar{x}_2(t)\right)+\bar{x}_1(t)=u(t) $$

And this is exactly what `NonlinearStateSpace` model does. It does not throw out anything when converting it to a state-space representation.

```
nssm1 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[eq1, x[t], u[t], x[t], t]
```

> [image]

Therefore the simulations match.

```
OutputResponse[nssm1, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 5}];
NDSolve[Join[eq1 /. u[t] -> UnitStep[t], {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}], x[t], {t, 0, 5}];
p1 = Plot[Evaluate@Join[%, %%], {t, 0, 5}]
```

> [image]

Now consider another model which has the nonlinearity in the highest-order derivative $x''(t)$.

```
eq2 = {Sin[x''[t]] + Sin[ x'[t]] + x[t] == u[t]};
```

Then the second state-equation becomes

$$ \sin\left(\bar{x}_2'(t)\right)+\sin \left(\bar{x}_2(t)\right)+\bar{x}_1(t)=u(t) $$

This cannot be represented using `NonlinearStateSpaceModel`, which requires that the state derivatives all be linear. Thus it will return the same model as before after linearizing the nonlinearity.

```
nssm2 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[eq2, x[t], u[t], x[t], t]
```

> [image]

And, just to verify, the simulation matches the previous one.

```
OutputResponse[nssm2, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 5}];
Show[p1, Plot[%, {t, 0, 5}]]
```

> [image]

The complete nonlinear model is a different animal.

```
NDSolve[Join[eq2 /. u[t] -> UnitStep[t], {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}], x[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

> [image]

*Update:*

As zxczd mentions in the comments to this answer, the complete nonlinear model has multiple solutions. It's interesting to see that model linearized by `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` approximates just one of them.

```
{x''[t] == (x''[t] /. Solve[eq2, x''[t]][[1]]) /. C[1] -> 0};
NDSolveValue[{% /. u[t] -> UnitStep[t], {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}}, x, {t, 0, 5}];
Show[ListLinePlot[%, PlotStyle -> Dashed], p1, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, All}]
```

[image]

A bigger sample of possible solutions:

```
possibleeq = Thread[x''[t] == Re[x''[t] /. Solve[eq2, x''[t]] /. C[1] -> #]] & /@ 
Range[-5, 5] // Flatten; 
possiblesol = NDSolveValue[{# /. u[t] ->(*Sin@t*)1, {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}}, 
x, {t, 0, 5}] & /@ possibleeq; 
ListLinePlot[possiblesol]
```

[image]

Comment: The last example can be solved if you add `SolvedDelayed->True` to `NDSolve`.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. I believe it is not simply adding the option, right? Do the equations also have to be reformulated?

Comment: No, you just need this option :) , then `NDSolve` will be able to solve the problem with a DAE solver. You may want to read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871

Comment: I think `SolvedDelayed` has been deprecated in my version. `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"` works in that it returns the solution 1.

Comment: Yeah `SolveDelayed` is red in the notebook, but it just works well, and in certain case you can even circumvent bug with it. (See **remark** 1 here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133140/1871)

Comment: After a second thought I noticed your last example is not trivial, it actually has infinite many solutions, and `SolveDelayed` only find one by default. The following is a way to find more solutions: `possibleeq = 
  Thread[x''[t] == Re[x''[t] /. Solve[eq2, x''[t]] /. C[1] -> #]] & /@ Range[-5, 5] // 
   Flatten;
possiblesol = 
  NDSolveValue[{# /. u[t] ->(*Sin@t*)1, {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}}, x, {t, 0, 5}] & /@ 
   possibleeq;
ListLinePlot[possiblesol]`

Comment: Thank you. I will update my answer shortly with your additional input.

Comment: I wonder why Mathematica doesn't just solve for `x2'` to give `NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{x2, ArcSin[-Sin[x2] + u - x1]}}, {x1, 
  x2}, {u}]`, which yields the (or a) correct result.

Comment: The question then from the other end would be why solutions get omitted? What about something like $e^{x''}+\sin \left(x''\right)+\ldots$ which returns no solution? Incorporating solve as part of the linearization will also bake in a lot of hackery. With the current design, things are clean. And it is also flexible for cases like the example above where if a user can identify a particular solution and decides to go with it, they can reformulate the problem and specify it accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

My guess is to be able to have the same internal representations as for linear systems. It is not possible to represent a system using `A,B,C,D` state space standard matrices without the system being linear.

For example, say the ODE was not linear, as in $x''(t)+x^2(t)=1$. Convert to state space. Let $x_1=x,x_2=x'$. Taking derivatives gives $x_1'(t)=x_2,x_2'=x''=1-x_1^2$

Now, how will one write $x'=Ax$ for the above? Not possible

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}^{\prime}\\
x_{2}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
? & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So linearization is done around the operating point to be able to obtain linear state space internal representation, so the rest of the functions in state space could use them.  So close to this point, the solution is accurate.

```
u=UnitStep[t];
ode1=x1'[t]==u-x1[t] x2[t];
ode2=x2'[t]==u x2[t]+1;
solNDsolve=NDSolve[{ode1,ode2,x1[0]==0,x2[0]==0},x1,{t,0,2}];

ClearAll[u,x,t]
nsys=NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{u-x1 x2,u x2+1},{x1}},{{x1,0},{x2,0}},u];
solState=OutputResponse[nsys,UnitStep[t],{t,0,5}];

Plot[{solState,Evaluate[x1[t]/.solNDsolve]},{t,0,2},
     PlotLegends->{"Nonlinear State Space solution","NDSolve solution"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To change the initial conditions, then

```
u=UnitStep[t];
ode1=x1'[t]==u-x1[t] x2[t];
ode2=x2'[t]==u  x2[t]+1;
solNDsolve=NDSolve[{ode1,ode2,x1[0]==1,x2[0]==1},x1,{t,0,2}];

ClearAll[u,x,t]
nsys=NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{u-x1 x2,u x2+1},{x1}},{{x1,1},{x2,1}},u];
solState=OutputResponse[nsys,UnitStep[t],{t,0,2}];

Plot[{solState,Evaluate[x1[t]/.solNDsolve]},{t,0,2},
      PlotLegends->{"Nonlinear State Space solution","NDSolve solution"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You gave `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` a bad rap. :) What you mark as 'state-space solution' is actually 'linear state-space solution' and you could just have used `StateSpaceModel`. `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` is a bigger fish.

Comment: @SubaThomas  I am sorry, I am using the help example as is in the above.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html and compared its output to `NDSolve`. If you mean the label on my plot should have the word `Nonlinear` added to it, Ok, I can do that. But I thought from the context it was clear it is using `Nonlinear state space`. But will change the labels now.

Comment: Looking at your code a little more closely, I see the mistake you made. The second rhs (for ode2) you entered in `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` should be u- x2+1. Then the solutions agree.  Initially, I looked at your original equation (with no nonlinearity in the highest derivative) and attributed the differences in the solutions to you having linearized the equations. I now realize, you are missing a negative sign. (I did not also follow how you got ode1 and ode2 from the original ode you have. But that's a different issue.)

Comment: @SubaThomas sorry about this typo again.  I will correct that now also. I got the original ode1 and ode2 from the help page itself.   ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JJwWU.png)  when I typed it by hand for `NDSolve` I made the mistake. Will fix soon

Comment: Thanks Nasser. Sorry about my lack of diligence initially. To avoid confusion to anyone else who may read these comments, let me add that this answer illustrates that `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` does not do any linearization when there is no nonlinearity in the highest-order derivatives. There is perfect agreement in the simulations whether one uses `OutputResponse` or directly calls `NDSolve` (which is what `OutputResponse` does behind the scenes.)