# Solving a system of partial differential and algebraic equations? setting the step-size to get reasonable results

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics, nonlinear, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to use Mathematica to get some early approximate solutions to a system of algebraic and partial differential equations. It is actually 1D model of an ideal gas in a tube. I'll divide my question into two parts so it will be more understandable:

- Part one:

I want to solve Navier–Stokes equations for a compressible inviscid isothermal fluid in a 1D tube:

1. $\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \left( \nu P \right)}{\partial u}=0$
2. $\frac{\partial \left(P \nu\right) }{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \left( P \nu^2 \right) }{\partial u}+\mathring{R} T_a\frac{\partial P}{\partial u}=0$

Initial condition:

1. $\nu\left( u,0 \right)=0$
2. $P\left( u,0 \right)=1$

Dirichlet boundary condition (step signal)

$\left\{\begin{matrix} if \, t<1  \, then &  \nu\left( 0,t \right)=0 \\ else &  P\left( 0,t \right)=2 \end{matrix}\right.$

and $P\left( 1,t \right)=1$

I know I can use NDSolveValue and NDSolve to have some numerical solutions. for example I used the command below to solve a simplified version of the above system of PDEs:

```
pval = NDSolveValue[{D[p[x, t]*v[x, t], x] + D[p[x, t], t] == 0, 
D[p[x, t], x] + D[p[x, t]*v[x, t]^2, x] + D[p[x, t]*v[x, t], t] == 
0, p[0, t] == UnitStep[t - 1] + 1, p[1, t] == 1, p[x, 0] == 1, 
v[x, 0] == 0}, p, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 3}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "MaxPoints" -> 4000, "MinPoints" -> 4000}}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]
Dimensions[sol1["Grid"]]
```

but the result I get is pretty awful:

```
ContourPlot[pval[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2.2}]
```

[image]

and it does not go furthure than t=2.232...

My first guess I don't have the right temporal resolution, but I don't know how to set it like what I have found for spatial resolution.

But I would like to ask my question in a general form:

1. How should I solve this system of algebraic and PDEs. DSolve, NDSolveValue or NDSolve?
2. how to get reasonable solutions by setting the spatial and temporal step size?

   - Part two:

I would like to solve the Navier–Stokes equations for a compressible viscose adiabatic fluid in a 1D tube:

1. Ideal gas: $P=\mathring{R} T \rho$
2. conservation of mass: $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \left( \nu \rho \right)}{\partial u}=0$
3. conservation of linear momentum: $\frac{\partial \left(\rho \nu\right) }{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \left( \rho \nu^2 \right) }{\partial u}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial u}-\frac{4\mu\nu}{D}=0$
4. conservation of heat for a control volume, assuming the Newtonian viscose fluid, the conduction/radiation is negligible (adiabatic for the whole tube): $\mu\nu^2=\frac{cD}{4}\left( 
   \frac{\partial\left( T\rho\nu \right)}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial \left(\rho T \right)}{\partial t} \right)$

these equations in Mathematica format:

```
p[x, t] == T[x, t]*q[x, t]
D[q[x, t]*v[x, t], x] + D[q[x, t], t] == 0
D[p[x, t], x] + D[q[x, t]*v[x, t]^2, x] + D[q[x, t]*v[x, t], t] -v[x,t]==0
v[x, t]^2 - D[T[x, t]*q[x, t]*v[x, t], x] == 0
```

Where $\mathring{R}$, $\nu$, $D$ and $c$ are constants. $P$, $\rho$, $\nu$ and $T$ are functions of $x$ and $t$

I would like to ask my question in a general form:

1. How should I solve this system of algebraic and PDEs. DSolve, NDSolveValue or NDSolve?
2. how to get reasonable solutions by setting the spatial and temporal step size?

P.S. I'm not able to get the right tags for my post!

Comment: `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue` in general produce the same result,. `DSolve` is unlikely to produce a solution for this nonlinear problem.  Your plot suggests that the solution may be unstable numerically for the parameters chosen.

Comment: @bbgodfrey you are right, there were some mistakes. I also updated the code and the picture

Comment: With `MaxStepSize -> {10^-3, 2 10^-4}]`, the computation goes beyond `2.23` without difficulty, although it does show signs of numerical instability beyond `t == 5`.  What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: I would like to solve the system of PDEs I mentioned. That's the main question.

Comment: Well, if you can help me with the complete version it would be the best. I think I kind of made mistake adding the simplified version to this question. sorry for that. I just added the Mathemathica code to the question

Comment: @bbgodfrey first of all thanks a lot for being patient and answering my question. I still don't have the upvote privilege otherwise I would do that. secondly. I spent sometime cleaning the question and making it more structured.

Comment: `p[0, t] == UnitStep[t - 1] + 1` does not accurately represent your `x == 0` boundary condition.  Also, you may wish to delete some of the old material now at the end of your question.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey 1. you are right about the boundary condition. but I still don't know how to include that discrete "if-statement" as a boundary condition 2. There is a lot for me to learn about NDSolve. I'm going to spend some time learning and adding them to your answer or a new one. 3. I'm thinking of moving the second part to a new question maybe. it is too long. 4. "the end of your question" do you mean the P.S. about tags? I still think there aren't enough tags. for example NDSolve should be a tag, PDE should also be one.

Comment: 1) Probably, it is necessary to discretize by hand the PDE into a set of ODEs to accommodate the boundary condition.  2)  Visit [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) to learn much more about `NDSolve`.  3) Focus on the simple question first.  4) I recommend against creating new tags, which only causes confusion; the ones I added should be sufficient.  5) Delete comments that no longer are relevant.

Comment: As pointed out by @bbgodfrey, your question seems to be similar to the one linked below. If they're really the same type of question, then your b.c. is mistakenly given. If they're not, your b.c. still looks suspicious: there's no b.c. for $\nu$ when $t>1$?

Comment: @xzczd honestly I was too hasty posting the question. it is too big and confusing. I need to spend some time, pinpointing individual issues and then come back and divide the question into multiple ones. about the boundary condition. it is actually a valve at u=0. so when it opens the pressure is the reservoir pressure and when it closes, the velocity is zero. is it a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I should say. As mentioned above, I just feel it suspicious, there does exist some special cases (for example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9277/1871)), but _usually_ b.c. for $\nu$ is needed for all time.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution of "Simplified Version" with Original BC**

The following modifications to the "simplified version" of this hydrodynamics problem with the boundary condition, `p[0, t] == 0.1*t + 1` (now replaced by the OP), allows the computation to be carried out to `t == 10`, but not much beyond.

```
{pval, vval} = NDSolveValue[{D[p[x, t]*v[x, t], x] + D[p[x, t], t] == 0 , 
   D[p[x, t], x] + D[p[x, t]*v[x, t]^2, x] + D[p[x, t]*v[x, t], t] == 0, 
   p[0, t] == 0.1*t + 1, p[1, t] == 1, p[x, 0] == 1, v[x, 0] == 0}, 
   {p, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
       {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 1000, "MinPoints" -> 1000}}, 
   MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 5 10^-4}]
```

> NDSolveValue::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 168.55610168929198`at t = 10.` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 1000 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options.

In fact, reducing the spatial and temporal step sizes does not help much, and I suspect that some form of artificial viscosity may be needed.  Here are plots of the results.  Spurious fine-scale behavior is evident in  the first plot.

```
ContourPlot[pval[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[vval[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note that a similar problem is solved in [11748](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11748/1063), although I am a bit suspicious of the two approaches employed.

**Solution of "Simplified Version" with Present BC**

The desired boundary condition formally is `If[t < 1, v[0, t] == 0, p[0, t] == 2]`.  However, I do not believe that `NDSolve` can handle this boundary condition for nonlinear PDEs.  There is, however, a straightforward equivalent approach.  The initial and boundary conditions for `t < 1` yield the solution {pval[x, t] == 1, vval[x, t] ==0}, both analytically and numerically.  So, beginning the calculation with `p[0, t] == 2` might seem like the natural course of action.  Unfortunately, `NDSolve` (correctly) complains about inconsistency between the initial and boundary conditions for `p` at `{x == 0, t == 0}` and replaces the boundary condition by `p[0, t] == 2 - Exp[1 - t]]`, after which it runs more or less as desired.  Specifically, with the boundary conditions just described explicitly included, the code and results are

```
{pval, vval} = NDSolveValue[{D[p[x, t]*v[x, t], x] + D[p[x, t], t] == 0, 
    D[p[x, t], x] + D[p[x, t]*v[x, t]^2, x] + D[p[x, t]*v[x, t], t] == 0, 
    p[0, t] == 2 - Exp[1 - t], p[1, t] == 1, p[x, 1] == 1, v[x, 1] == 0}, 
    {p, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 1, 10}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 1000, 
    "MinPoints" -> 1000}}, MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 5 10^-4}];
```

> NDSolveValue::eerr: Warning ... (as above)

```
ContourPlot[Piecewise[{{pval[x, t], t > 1}}, 1], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Piecewise[{{vval[x, t], t > 1}}, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

In addition to the obvious noise, which as before is due to numerical instability, a sheath has formed very near `x == 0` for `t > 5` (approximately).  The cause of this sheath is unclear to me.  Note that increasing the spatial and temporal resolution has little effect.

Comment: @bbgodfery I am still doing lots of research to solve this issue. but your point regarding the weird initial condition is valid. I have already realized not just Mathetica, but not other methods do not not work if the boundary condition is not smooth enough.  P.S. there is one curly brackets missing in your third plot command :)

Comment: @Foad  Typo corrected.  Thanks.