# Finite difference method not converging to correct steady state or conserving area?

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations, finite-difference-method

I am working with the following PDE, which is an advection-diffusion type equation. It describes the movement of a fluid-fluid interface inside an annulus of inner radius $R_1$ and outer $R_2$ under the action of gravity, where one fluid is denser than another. I am trying to solve it via a finite-difference scheme. I am working in polar coordinates.

$h_t + \left[(h-R_1)^2(h-R_2)^2(h_\theta \sin \theta 
  +h\cos \theta)\right]_\theta = 0$

The physical steady state for this system is a flat interface (dense fluid runs downhill until it all collects in the bottom of the annulus with light fluid above). We can check if the physical intuition of flat interface final state truly is a steady state solution ($h_t = 0$) of our PDE.

Indeed, if we ignore trivial steady states of $h = R_1$ and $h = R_2$ which correspond to the interface being on an annulus boundary (ie. annulus entirely filled with only one fluid) then, $h_t = 0$ when $(h_\theta \sin \theta 
  +h\cos \theta) = const$. Solving this (WLOG $const$ = 0) leads us to $h = C\csc\theta$, which indeed corresponds to flat $y = C$ solutions.

Additionally clearly the PDE also conserves area, as it can be written in flux conservative form.

So now I attempt to solve this PDE with an initial interface position, and march time forward until the interface relaxes to the physical steady state solution.

Let us set $R_1 = 1, R_2 = 2$.

My finite difference code is as follows:

```
n = 201; 
ds = 1./n;
ClearAll[dh, t];
dh[h_List] := 
  With[{s = Array[# &, n, {-5/6 π, -π/6}], 
    d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/ds, #] &, 
    d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/ds^2, #] &}, 

(* Setting up the grid, derivatives etc. *)

(-2 + h) (-1 + h) (-4 Cos[s] d1[#1] - 6 (-2 + h) h Cos[s] d1[#1] + (6 d1[#1]^2 - 2 d2[#1] + h (2 + h^2 - 4 d1[#1]^2 + 3 d2[#1] - h (3 + d2[#1]))) Sin[s]) &@Join[{2}, h, {2}]];
```

The PDE, with Dirichlet conditions added to the end points, such that the interface stays on the outer boundary.

```
h0 = Flatten@Join[ConstantArray[1.999, 51], ConstantArray[1.001, 100], ConstantArray[1.999, 50]];
```

Initial condition

```
sol = NDSolve[{h'[t] == dh[h[t]], h[0] == h0}, h, {t, 0, 5}][[1, 1, 2]];
```

We can now visualise the solution

```
Needs@"DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`";
valh = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid@sol;
ti = Flatten@InterpolatingFunctionGrid@sol;
s = Array[# &, n, {-5/6 π, -π/6}];
h = ListInterpolation[valh, {ti, s}]
```

To aid with visualisation. I will plot the line at which the steady state should lie, which can be calculated from simple geometry.

```
ListAnimate@Table[Show[PolarPlot[Evaluate[h[ti, θ]], {θ, -5/6 π, -π/6}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> Black], 
RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1], AspectRatio -> 1], 
PolarPlot[2 Sin[-2.4539664700963293`]/ Sin[θ], {θ,-2.4539664700963293`, -0.6876261834934637`}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {ti, 0, 5, 0.1}]
```

We can see from looking at snapshots in time, that the current initially does as expected. Slumping and running, but then something strange happens, it "overshoots" the steady state and goes under it. Clearly not conserving volume (area). It then appears to tend to the $h = 2$ steady state.

[image]

I am a bit perplexed about why it is doing this? There must be an error with my finite difference scheme?

**EDIT - Further Details**

If I make the initial condition something a little "nicer", a smooth parabolic shape for example. The system can be solved easily by `NDSolve`. In this case, the interface tends to the correct (physically intuitive) steady state and conserves area. This suggests to me that there is an error in my FTCS finite difference scheme.

Here is the code:

```
 pde = D[h[θ, t], t] == -D[(-1 + h[θ, t])^2 (h[θ, t] -2)^2 (Cos[θ] h[θ, t] + Sin[θ] D[h[θ, t], θ]), θ];

sol = NDSolve[{pde, h[-((5 π)/6), t] == 1.999, h[-(π/6), t] ==1.999, h[θ, 0] == 2.3102500000000017` + 0.7133324549378759` θ + 0.22706077254247925` θ^2}, h, {θ, -((5 π)/6), -(π/6)}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]

ListAnimate@
 Table[Show[
   PolarPlot[
    Evaluate[
     h[θ, t] /. sol], {θ, -((5 π)/6), -(π/6)}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    PlotStyle -> Black], 
    PolarPlot[2*Sin[-2.217941839687187`]/Sin[x], {x, -2.217941839687187`, -0.9236508139026061`}, PlotStyle -> Red]
   RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1], AspectRatio -> 1]], {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

[image]

If I try and use `NDSolve` with my desired initial condition. I use

```
int = Interpolation[Transpose@{s,h0}]
```

however, I get an error about the PDE being stiff. I presume this is because of the large gradients seen at the nose of the current in the first gif.

Comment: There're typos in your code,  you'd better recheck it, for example, what's `valu`? The argument of `dh[h]` is limited to `List`, so `dh[h[t]]` will just return unevaluated.

Comment: Amended the `valu`, it's meant to be a `valh`. Don't know what you mean about `dh[h[t]]`being unevaluated. The `NDSolve` returns an `InterpolatingFunction` of dimension n as required?

Comment: I should say I'm somewhat surprised. I did know that the ability of `NDSolve` for handling vectors is improved, but didn't expect that it can handle function definition like `h[t_List]` now. Just a side note: in a 2GHz laptop it takes about 85 seconds to solve for `{t, 0, 1}`.

Comment: Can you add some more background information of the equation? (Where does it come from, in what text can one find it, how can one derive it etc.) I guess that might help.

Comment: I agree with @xzczd and surely some background is needed for us to optimize the solution. BTW: hi xzczd, we met again at this site after 3 years~

Comment: @wjx I'm glad to see you're able to post non-downvoted question/answer now :)

Comment: The equation is derived from considering lubrication theory in polar coordinates with two different density fluids. Given that the flow is lubrication, we can assume pressure to be hydrostatic in the radial direction. So the flow is a balance of viscous stresses, gravity and pressure gradients in the azimuthal direction. You can then solve this system for the velocity of both fluids, with a matching velocity and tangential stress condition at the interface and a no slip boundary condition on the walls. These velocities contain an unknown interface function $h_\theta$.

Comment: To obtain a time dependent PDE for $h$. We can then use the mass continuity equation $h_t + \frac{1}{R_1}Q_{L_{\theta}} = 0$. Where $Q_L$ is the flux in the lower layer. We obtain the flux by integrating the velocities and using the fact that pressure must be continuous around the annulus. ie. $\int_0^{2\pi} p_\theta \: d\theta= 0$. I have then nondimensionalised the equation.

Comment: Er… do you derive the equation yourself or by referring to some material?

Comment: Derive it myself

Comment: @xzczd perhaps a finite volume method might be a better approach?

Comment: Well, I guess the root of the problem isn't in numeric method you choose, but probably in modeling, but since I'm not familiar with lubrication theory, it's hard for me to check if the equation and the assumption for the boundary condition are correct. I just want to mention one thing that I feel suspicious: can "**nothing** at the boundary" be modeled as `h[-Pi/6] ==h[-5Pi/6]==2`?

Comment: @xzczd I believe the problem is numeric. I think this type of PDE is not stable to the FTCS method I have employed. The modelling is sound as simple checks such as a physical steady state can be shown. Also the PDE is has similar terms to other canonical gravity currents. See Huppert 1982, Gunn Woods 2010

Comment: Well, the scheme you chose seems to be stable actually, you can modify the domain of `t` to something like `{t, 0, 20}` (This takes about 140 seconds in my PC, of course you need `MaxSteps->Infinity` option in this case) and observe the result, you'll see the solution does converge to a steady state, but not the one you're expecting.

Comment: @xzczd If I modify the initial condition to something smooth I can use `NDSolve` without writing my own FD scheme. I observe that using `NDSolve` the PDE tends to the correct (physically intuitive) steady state. If I then use this same initial condition in my FD scheme, the PDE tends to the wrong steady state. Therefore I conclude there must be an error with my scheme. It's a shame `NDSolve` can't handle my desired initial condition without getting itself in a twist. I can provide further details on the working smooth initial condition case if you'd like?

Comment: "I can provide further details on the working smooth initial condition case if you'd like?" I think it'll be good if you add this to your question. "It's a shame `NDSolve` can't handle my desired initial condition without getting itself in a twist." So a fully `NDSolve` based solution is OK to you, if `NDSolve` is able to solve it? As far as I can tell, `NDSolve` can handle discontinued initial condition (at least in some cases), how did you set that discontinued initial condition in `NDSolve`?

Comment: @xzczd I have added this information to the question. To use the desired initial condition, I just interpolated `h0`. `NDSolve` gets upset about the equation being stiff. This is because of the shock formation near the nose of the current - you can see this in the first gif. I would happily use `NDSolve` if it could handle these large gradients, but I'm not sure how? This is why I decided to write my own FD instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Introduction

A lack of time to write up an answer ironically provided time to reflect on the problem, and some nagging uncertainties about some issues contributed to the delay.

The slowness of the OP's code can be seen by a simple analysis, which reveals that some expensive calculations are repeated multiple times for each step in the time integration.  A more important concern is whether area is conserved by the DE. The OP asserts yes, but I'm thinking not.  I wonder which of us is correct. This issue has slowed my response, because I assumed area was conserved, which led to things not making sense.  I first thought I could explain the change in area in terms of the finite-difference discretization.  It does contribute to it, but not as much as the underlying differential equation.  This was confusing to me until I accepted the hypothesis that area is not conserved.  Similarly, a difference of opinion about the proper value of the grid spacing `ds` has made me hesitate some.

### Code analysis

The OP's code for `dh[]` is clearly written and this is plugged into a simple straight-forward `NDSolve` call, so the whole is not hard to analyze.

**Dependence and independence**

I have found that I save myself some headaches if variables that depend on one another are constructed in code that reflects the dependency. Let's look at some of the quantities in the code, in particular `s` and `ds`.

First, **`ds`** and **`s`** are intimately linked to each, but their codes are independent.  This is a weakness and a potential source for bugs.  We should have `ds = s[[2]] - s[[1]]` (since it is a regular grid).
Similarly, **`h0`** depends on `n` but is not defined in terms of `n`; indeed, it probably ought to be a function of `θ` and applied to `s`.

**Control flow**

The principal thing to notice is that in `dh[]`, each of `d1[#]` and `d2[#]` is repeated several times and each entails a `ListCorrelate[]` computation to be repeated.  This will slow things down unnecessarily.
By contrast, @xzczd's fast solution calculates `dh[h]` just once; even though it is a symbolic computation and somewhat slower than a numerical one, it is not nearly as slow as repeating calculations again and again throughout the steps of the time integration.

**Leveraging *Mathematica***

**1.**
As shown in the tutorial, [The Numerical Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[] `` will compute finite difference derivatives.  It is virtually the same as the OP's `ListCorrelation[]` codes (with the appropriate `"DifferenceOrder"`, with one difference: `FiniteDifferenceDerivative[]` uses a higher order approximation at the end points of the grid instead of padding (as the OP does with `{2.}`).  The OP's results may be obtained by manually padding in the same way and dropping the first and last results from `FiniteDifferenceDerivative[]`.  For instance, these give the same results as `d1` and `d2` respectively:

```
s = Array[# &, n, {-5/6 π, -π/6}];
ds = s[[2]] - s[[1]];  (* == Pi/300 for n = 201 *)
paddedgrid = Join[{First[s] - ds}, s, {Last[s] + ds}];
paddedh0 = Join[{2.}, h0, {2.}];

NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, paddedgrid,    (* == d1[h0] *)
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2][paddedh0][[2 ;; -2]]
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, paddedgrid,    (* == d2[h0] *)
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 1][paddedh0][[2 ;; -2]]
```

Note that `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative `` does not depend on `ds` and can be used just in terms of `s`.

**2.**
A minor point: The following is equivalent to the OP's use of `ListCorrelation`, padding `h` with `2.` on the left and right:

```
d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/ds, h, {-2, 2}, 2.]
d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/ds^2, h, {-2, 2}, 2.]
```

**3.**
In addition, the OP's use of `dh[h[t]]`, with `dh[h_List]`, means that `NDSolve` will treat `dh[]` as a numeric black box, whereas , @xzczd's `dh[h]` constructs a (large) system of symbolic equations. It seems clear, from the difference in the number of steps shown below, that this affects the integration method used by `NDSolve`.

### Improvement of speed in `dh[]`

Aside from eliminating the redundant computations outline above, the use of machine numbers, [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array), and vectorized operations, as discussed in 
[Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica), can be used to increase speed.  `Compile` also helps quite a bit.
(The code for `Compile` was constructed from the OP's ode, and I used `$` variables to avoid conflicting with other things.)  One could do it with the padded grid shown above, which would add a little to the computation time, but I'll do it with the simpler approach.

```
ClearAll[dh2, s];

n = 201;
s = Developer`ToPackedArray@N@Array[# &, n, {-5/6 π, -π/6}];

dhC = Compile[{{$h, _Real, 1}, {$d1, _Real, 1}, {$d2, _Real, 1},
               {$s, _Real, 1}, {$c, _Real, 1}},
   -2 $d1 (-2 + $h)^2 (-1 + $h) ($c $h + $d1 $s) - 
    2 $d1 (-2 + $h) (-1 + $h)^2 ($c $h + $d1 $s) -
    (-2 + $h)^2 (-1 + $h)^2 (2 $c $d1 + $d2 $s - $h $s)
   ];

With[{ (* compute derivatives and Sin[s], Cos[s] just once *)
   d1FN = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, s, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2],
   d2FN = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, s, "DifferenceOrder" -> 1],
   sin = Sin[s],
   cos = Cos[s]},
 dh2[h_List] := With[{d1 = d1FN@h, d2 = d2FN@h},
   dhC[h, d1, d2, sin, cos]]
 ];
```

**Performance comparison**

I wanted to compare evaluations of the right-hand side of the ODE, steps, and time.  I added an option `EvaluationMonitor :> ++evals` to the `NDSolve` code for each case.  I timed the solutions with code like the following one for my case:

```
{sol2} = h /. NDSolve[{h'[t] == dh2[h[t]], h[0] == h0}, h, {t, 0, 10}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> ++evals]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

***Oddly,*** adding `EvaluationMonitor` to @xzczd's method increased the time by a huge factor (it took twice as long as mine), so I retimed it without the monitor, where @xzczd's took half the time mine did.  These were done with a corrected `ds`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see that `dh2` evaluates about twice as fast, counted per evaluation, than @xzczd's method and 100 times faster than the OP's.  Whether that is an entirely fair comparison depends on how much evaluating the ODE accounts for the execution time of `NDSolve`.  It should account for a lot of it, but that's just my guess.

### Area preserving?

I figure I should share this.  If I made a mistake, well, someone can point it out.  If not, then, maybe it will help the OP.  If we consider what it means to be area-preserving, we should consider the integral
$$A = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \text{$1\over2$}\, h(t,\theta)^2\;d\theta \,,$$
where $h$ is extended to $-\pi \le \theta \le \pi$ by defining $h(t,\theta) = 2$ (that is, the greater radius) outside $-5\pi/6 \le \theta \le -\pi/6$.
Then, by my lights, differentiating under the integral sign, the rate of change of the area is given by
$${dA \over dt} = \int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t,\theta)h_t(t,\theta)\;d\theta$$
and $h_t$ can be written in terms of $h$, $h_\theta$, $h_{\theta\theta}$ using the PDE.

Of course, an equilibrium solution will preserve area.  But if we perturb an equilibrium solution, then $dA/dt$ is nonzero:

```
ClearAll[dhdt, dAdt];
Block[{h, θ},
 dhdt[h_, θ_] = -D[(h[θ] - 2)^2 (h[θ] - 1)^2 D[h[θ] Sin[θ], θ], θ];
 ];
dAdt[hfn_] := NIntegrate[hfn[θ] dhdt[hfn, θ], {θ, -Pi, Pi}];

(* background *)
θ1 = -2.4539664700963293`;
background = Show[
   RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1], AspectRatio -> 1],
   PolarPlot[
    2 Sin[θ1]/Sin[θ], {θ, θ1, -(Pi + θ1)}, 
    PlotStyle -> Black]
   ];

solPlot[hfn_] := Show[
   background,
   PolarPlot[hfn, {θ, -5/6 π, -π/6},
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][
        0.5 (1 + Clip[100 dhL /. h -> Function @@ {θ, hfn} /. θ -> #3, {-1,1}])] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
   ];

Block[{Print, θ2 = θ1, eps = +0.1, hf},
 hf = Piecewise[{
     {2 Sin[θ2] Csc[#] + eps (# - θ2) (# + Pi + θ2), θ2 < # < -Pi - θ2}
     }, 2] &;
 Show[solPlot[hf[θ]], PlotLabel -> Row[{"dA/dt = ", dAdt[hf]}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Red means the radius `h` is decreasing; green means it is increasing (with respect to time in the DE.)

### The effect of finite differences and the error in `ds`

Using `Block` and the OP's definition of `dh`, we can see what happens when we use different values for `ds`.  There is some controversy about the correct value for `ds`, and it is my view that it should be equal to the differences in `s`.  The padding by `2` on either side of `h` in for `ListCorrelate[]` in the OP's `dh[]` corresponds to using `s == -5 Pi/ 6 - ds` and `s == -Pi / 6 + ds` and corresponds to the (unused) condition that `h` is identically equal to `2` outside the interval `{-5 Pi/6, -Pi/6}`.

If we plot `dh[h[s]]`, where `h` is the equilibrium solution of the OP, `h[s] = 2 Sin[θ1] Csc[s]` for a given `θ1`, and `s` is the input grid as above, we will see how close to zero the value of `dh` is for the finite difference scheme.

```
ClearAll[dhEquilPlot];
SetAttributes[dhEquilPlot, Listable];
θ1 = -2.4539664700963293`;
dhEquilPlot[ds0_] := Block[{ds = ds0},
  ListPlot[
   dh[Clip[2 Sin[θ1] Csc[s], {0., 2.}]],
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"ds = ", ds}], Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {HoldForm[s], HoldForm[h'[t]]}, DataRange -> MinMax[s], 
   BaseStyle -> {FractionBoxOptions -> {Beveled -> True}}
   ]
  ]

dhEquilPlot /@ {
   {1/n},                               (* OP     (UL) *)
   {(-(π/6) - -((5 π)/6))/(n + 2 - 1),  (* xzczd  (LL) *)
    (-(π/6) - -((5 π)/6))/(n - 1)}      (* M E2   (LR) *)
   } // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see how much closer to zero `dh` is for `ds = Pi/300`, which is also the grid spacing in `s`.
It is also clear that in all three cases, the radius `h` is pulled toward the center (`dh < 0`) near where the level of the fluid contacts the outside circle (where `h` reaches `2`).  Of course the actual evolution from the OP's starting configuration will be slightly different.  But since physically, the model should be area-preserving, there is little point in exploring this beyond determining the value of `ds` until the issue with area is cleared up.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth reply. After some long thought I have deduced that the quantity that is conserved is $V = R_1 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h \, \, d\theta$ and not the usual definition of area in polar coordinates with $1/2$ and $h^2$ term. This is due to the lubrication approximations made during the derivation of the PDE.

Comment: @ojlm You're welcome.  And yes, I agree that $V$ should be conserved.

Comment: Actually those `$`s inside `Compile` isn't necessary, `Compile` owns the attribute `HoldAll` :)

Comment: @xzczd The formula in `Compile` was generated by code not shown that did not hold the variables. I may have wanted the formula for several purposes at the time, but I've forgotten why I did it this way.

Answer (score 18):

Since a fully `NDSolve`-based solution is acceptable for you, let me give you one. You simply need the [magic of "Pseudospectral"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9291/1871) or a dense enough 4th order spatial discretization:

```
mol[n_, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

ic[θ_] = Piecewise[{{1.001, -2 Pi/3 < θ < -Pi/3}}, 1.999];

(* Solution 1 *)    
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, h[-5 π/6, t] == 1.999, h[-π/6, t] == 1.999, 
   h[θ, 0] == ic@θ}, h, {θ, -5 π/6, -π/6}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> mol[101]]

(* Solution 2, NDSolveValue will spit out eerri warning but it doesn't matter. *)
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{pde, h[-5 π/6, t] == 1.999, h[-π/6, t] == 1.999, 
    h[θ, 0] == ic@θ}, h, {θ, -5 π/6, -π/6}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method ->mol[400, 4]];

pic = RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1]];

ListAnimate@Table[Show[PolarPlot[sol[θ, t], {θ, -5 π/6, -π/6}, 
  PlotRange -> 2, PlotStyle -> Black], pic], {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]

ListAnimate@Table[Show[PolarPlot[sol2[θ, t], {θ, -5 π/6, -π/6}, 
  PlotRange -> 2, PlotStyle -> Black], pic], {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

[image]

OK, now the remaining problem is what's wrong with the FD scheme. Somewhat awkwardly, I found the root of evil is actually a simple mistake: the definition of `ds` should be

```
ds = (-(π/6) - -((5 π)/6))/(n - 1)
```

With this line corrected, your code outputs desired result, too.

Another thing I want to mention is, though (it's surprising to me that) `NDSolve` still manages to handle implicit vector in your case, it's much faster to define the list of unknown functions explicitly. The following approach is about **180 times faster** than yours:

```
Clear@h;
sol = With[{h = h[#][t] & /@ Range@n}, 
    NDSolveValue[{D[h, t] == dh[h], (h /. t -> 0) == h0}, 
     Head /@ h, {t, 0, 10}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.770651, Null} <- on contrast your approach takes about 140 seconds on my laptop*)


valh = Transpose[#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ sol];
ti = Flatten@sol[[1]]["Grid"];
s = Array[# &, n, {-5/6 π, -π/6}];

h = ListInterpolation[valh, {ti, s}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.860209, Null} *)
```

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: @user21  It is by standing on the shoulders of yours :D

Comment: @xzczd Excellent answer, I had no idea about Pseudospectral as an option of `NDSolve`. Great spot on the FD error also!

Comment: @xzczd I do have a further question. How come if I increase the number of points in the argument of `mol` (to increase the accuracy of the solution) `NDSolve` complains about the solution being stiff again? For example, if I increase to 501 points the solution is stiff at $t = 0.847 $. If I go to 201 points, the solution is not stiff, but there is numerical instability after $t \sim 7 $

Comment: @ojlm Sorry, I'm not able to answer this. I know `"Pseudospectral"` seems to be quite effective on certain kind of PDEs (specifically speaking, PDEs related to fluid dynamics and quantum mechanics, according to the examples appearing in this site so far), I also observed some mysterious behavior of it (it may fail if the grid points isn't "proper" or a non-`MachinePrecision` `WorkingPrecision` is set), but I never looked into the reason. Maybe you can consider asking it in http://scicomp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @ojlm The main difference in speed between the vector and the component-wise versions is the way `dh` is computed.  In the vector one, `dh` is uncompilable and the `d1` and `d2` list correlations are computed **several times** at each step; in the component-wise one, `dh[h]` is computed only once and then passed to `NDSolve`, which then (probably) compiles the expression.  There are much faster ways to write `dh`, but my attempts don't beat the component-wise one (because of a difference the automatic time-integration method -- mine takes 10000+ steps and xzczd's takes 3600+).

Comment: @ojlm My guess about the "stiffness" is that it arises from the singularity where the interface meets the boundary. Theoretically `h` is not θ-differentiable there, and numerically that should mean trouble as `h` approaches `2` at the ends. A finer mesh only focuses on the trouble, where a coarser mesh tends to average out the spikes. Caveat: PDEs are not my specialty, and I don't know how to address this in `NDSolve`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 "There are much faster ways to write `dh`" This sounds interesting, how about giving an example?

Comment: I think you want `ds = (-(π/6) - -((5 π)/6))/(n - 1)`.  (I'll give an example for `dh` in an answer I hope to post soon.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think for OP's code it should be `n + 2 - 1` because he added the b.c. by `Join[{2}, h, {2}]`.

Comment: I was thinking that `ds` should be equal to the value in `Differences[s]`.  (Or the bordering of `h` needs to correspond to a similar bordering of `s`, since `h` itself represents the values on all of `s`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I look forward to your answer as my FD scheme goes to the right steady state, but I'm afraid does not conserve area. Also, the `NDSolve` solution is not as useful as I first thought, as I cannot increase the points to ensure accuracy. As you rightly state, this is due to large gradients at the nose of the currents.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just read your answer, you're right. Corrected. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @ojlm `"Pseudospectral"` turns out to be unnecessary, check my edit.