# Numerical instabilities in a solution to a partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have been trying to solve a partial differential equation known as KdV (Korteweg-de Vries) equation using NDSolve.
KdV equation is written as:

$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^3 u(x,t)}{\partial x^3}=-6u(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}$

One of the analytical solution of this equation is a Jacobi elliptical function
$u_{A} = \text{A JacobiCN}[B*(x- c t),m]^2$
where A, B, c and m are known parameters.

So the initial condition is
$u_0 =  \text{A JacobiCN}[B*x,m]^2 $.

The boundary condition is:  $u(t,-a) = u(t,a)$.

Code for analytical solution is

```
a = 30; m = 0.9; A = 0.9;
B = Sqrt[1.5*A] / Sqrt[2*m + m^2]
c = 6*(-A + A*m + A*m^2)/(m*(2 + m))
uA[x_,t_] := A*JacobiCN[B*(x - c*t), m]^2;
Plot[uA[x,0.5], {x, -a, a}, LabelStyle ->  Directive[14, Bold,   Black], AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 14, Bold, Black], Style["uA", 14, Bold, Black]}]
```

Plot of analytical solution for t = 0.5

[image]

When I solve the partial differential equation using NDSolve, the numerical instabilities arise and the numerical solution doesn't match the analytical solution.

```
eq = {D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] == -6 u[x, t] D[u[x, t], {x, 1}], u[x, 0] == A*JacobiCN[B*x, m]^2, u[-a, t] == u[a, t]};
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -a, a}]
Plot[Evaluate[u[x, 0.5] /. sol], {x, -a, a}, LabelStyle ->  Directive[14, Bold, Black], AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 14, Bold, Black], Style["u", 14, Bold, Black]}]
```

[image]

I am also getting the warning message
`NDSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 10000 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x.`
I have tried different options and methods given in NDSolve documentation and also tried solutions given in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/i-failed-to-solve-a-set-of-one-dimension-fluid-mechanics-pdes-with-ndsolve/9291#9291  but nothing seems to be working.
Following method removed the warning message but there was no improvement in the numerical solution.

```
nxy = 500;
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -a, a}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> nxy, "MinPoints" -> nxy, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}, Method -> "Adams"}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
```

Comment: The `uA` isn't an analytic solution of `eq`, just try `Subtract @@@ eq /. u -> uA /. x -> a/2 /. t -> 5`. Please double check your equation system.

Comment: It is an exact solution. If I substitute the analytical solution into the partial differential equation and simplify it, I will get a common factor.  When I write JacobiDN and JacobiSN in terms of JacobiCN, this common factor goes to zero.

Comment: As shown in my last comment, numeric calculation indicates the `uA` doesn't satisfy the system. What do you mean by "If I substitute the analytical solution into the partial differential equation and simplify it, I will get a common factor. When I write JacobiDN and JacobiSN in terms of JacobiCN, this common factor goes to zero"? Can you show the code for this verification?

Comment: `u[x_, t_] := A*JacobiCN[B*(x - C1*t), m]^2; eq = Simplify[
  D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] + 6 u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], {x, 1}]];f1 = (1.9016506529947896` - 4.5800318543959` JacobiCN[1.0564725849971053` t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 0.9`]^2 + 2.678381201401112` JacobiDN[     1.0564725849971053` t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 0.9`]^2 -  2.4105430812610016` JacobiSN[1.0564725849971053` t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 0.9`]^2);`

Comment: `Simplify[f1 /. {JacobiSN[
      1.0564725849971053` t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 0.9`]^2 -> 
    1 - JacobiCN[1.0564725849971053` t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 
       0.9`]^2, 
   JacobiDN[1.0564725849971053` t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 
      0.9`]^2 -> ((1 - m^2) + 
      m^2 JacobiCN[1.0564725849971053` t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 
         0.9`]^2)}]`   Sorry I was having difficulty in writing the code in a single comment so I had to break it. f1 is the common factor you get after simplifying eq.

Comment: Please add the code to your question by clicking the edit button at the bottom left corner of the question. Then, 2nd replacing rule is wrong, try: ``JacobiDN[1.0564725849971053 t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 0.9]^2 -> ((1 - m^2) + 
     m^2 JacobiCN[1.0564725849971053 t - 0.7191949522280763` x, 0.9]^2) /. t -> 1/2 /. 
 x -> 2``